# android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android

I don't know what's the problem with this layout :

> ```
> <EditText 
>     android:id="@+id/search"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
>     android:hint="Search...">
>
>
> <ListView 
>     android:id="@+id/lv_data"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"    
>     android:layout_below="@id/search">
> </ListView>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/empty"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@id/lv_data"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
>     android:text="Not found!">
> </TextView></EditText></RelativeLayout>
> ```

here's the code :

> import java.util.List;
>
> ```
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.text.Editable;
> import android.text.TextWatcher;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.AdapterView;
> import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
> import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.widget.ListView;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher, OnItemClickListener
> {
>   private EditText search;
>   private ListView lv;
>   private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
>   private ArrayAdapter<Kamus> adapter;
>   private List<Kamus> ListKamus;
>
>   protected void oncreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>   {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>       lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_data);
>       lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
>       search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
>
>       dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
>
>       setData();
>
>       search.addTextChangedListener(this);
>       lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
>   }
>
>   private void setData()
>   {
>       ListKamus = dbHelper.getAllKamus();
>
>       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Kamus>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, ListKamus);
>       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
>   {
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
>   {
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
>   {
>       adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id)
>   {
>       Bundle b = new Bundle();
>       b.putString("istilah", adapter.getItem(position).getIstilah());
>       b.putString("arti", adapter.getItem(position).getArti());
>
>       Intent i = new Intent(this, ArtiActivity.class);
>       i.putExtras(b);
>       startActivity(i);
>   }
>   }
> ```

Graphical Layout show a warning :

```
Exception raised during rendering: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:756)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:451)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:686)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3028)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: clean and build your project once

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have  close your **< /EditText>** after other widget(UI).

So just remove that closed tag after ***ListView*** and ***TextView***  and do like :

```
<EditText 
 android:id="@+id/search"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
 android:hint="Search..."/> // Close your Tag here
```

Answer (score 2):

your **EditText** tag is not closed at proper place. you have **closed it after TextBox**. EditText cant contain other ui elements.

so it is assuming that the rest of the elements like ListView are children of EditText, 
and so it says EditText cant be cast to ViewGroup